# Convert C# hash function to Python

Tags: python, c#, hash

I'm a new developer.
I'm converting C# library to Python(3.8). I have hash function that get
a file and find its hash code.

In the original C# code the hash function return byte[32] array
but in Python I get hex code. I'm trying to find out how to return code in byte[32] too.

this is my python code:

```
  sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(logPath, "rb") as f:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        hash_code = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
```

this is the c# code:

```
     using (var fileStream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open))
        {
            fileStream.Position = position;

            var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
            hashValue = sha256.ComputeHash(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `sha256_hash.digest()`

Comment: thanks but then i get something like this: b',\xb3\xc1Mn"\xbf\xb6\x98\xb6\x97\xf2j\xa9u\x08u@\xea\xb3\x1f\x17\xc3"x\xd4_\xbb\x02Z(\xd5'

Comment: That is a byte string, that is the Python equivalent of a .NET byte array. Note the `b` in front of the quotation mark.

Comment: Oh i didn't know thanks a lot! and what if i want to concat to this byte string another string: 
arr = bytes("something", 'utf-8') . can i do that? ? they look different (one byte[7] and the first one is .NET byte array)

Comment: @MaayanPaz-Chen, `first_byte_string + second_byte_string` will do the trick. I strongly recommend you to spend 15 minutes reading [article about built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) in official python  docs.

Comment: i will read! thanks! :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght I recommend to write a proper answer. The question is technically unanswered, but basically you answered it already in the comments.

Comment: @jps, I prefer to not post answers containing one sentence, but okay, posted.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`hash.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest), which returns [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), if you want to get byte array, you should use [`hash.digest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) which returns [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).